# Событие при перемещении курсора вниз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок, при наводе мышки на этот блок появляется сверху другой блок. Хочется чтобы если курсор уходил вниз, блок исчезал, как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы хотите только добиться эффекта именно при движении курсор вниз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел на просторах инетрнета:

```
$("selector").mouseleave(function(e) {
                 var $this = $(this);
                    var bottom = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
                 if(e.pageY >= bottom){
                    $('selector').hide();
                 }
});
```